# make query to search fast data at MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm still trying to find out how to make a query to search fast data in MySQL. I try make a function but its still slow to search data. Here is my raw query

```
SELECT B.totResi as TotResi,C.totResi as TotDeliv,D.totResi as TotPending,E.totResi as TotRetur 
FROM Table1 A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) as totResi,Id_Table1 from Table2 group by Id_Table1) B ON A.ID=B.Id_Table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) as totResi,Id_Table1 from Table2 where status=0 group by Id_Table1) C ON A.ID=C.Id_Table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) as totResi,Id_Table1 from Table2 where status=1 group by Id_Table1) D ON A.ID=D.Id_Table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(ID) as totResi,Id_Table1 from Table2 where status=2 group by Id_Table1) E ON A.ID=E.Id_Table1 
WHERE A.ID=22340 order by A.ID desc
```

and I'm trying make a function like, this is one of my function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tot_resi (ID int) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE total INT;
SELECT count(a.ID) as totResi into total from Table2 a where a.Id_Table1=ID;
RETURN total;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and I call the funtion like this

```
SELECT tot_resi(22340) as TotResi,tot_resi_deliv(22340) as TotDeliv,tot_resi_pending(22340) as TotPending,tot_resi_retur(22340) as TotRetur
```

I already have an index at my `Id_Table1` at `Table2` but it still finds the data very slow, do you have any advice to make search data fast?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you trying to make a function or trying to search data quickly?

Comment: i trying to search data quickly, i have another query with a function and it's work and make search data fast . i dont know why this query above still search data really slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need simple

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id),
       SUM(t2.status=0),
       SUM(t2.status=1),
       SUM(t2.status=2)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.Id_Table1
WHERE t1.id=22340
```

Comment: i try make query base on this answer and its 2x fast than my query .